# @FindBy WebElements not initialized when using Guice @Inject

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cucumber, automated-tests, guice

I'm currently having some issues with implementing object injections properly. I am writing some Cucumber tests with Page Objects Model. I am getting `NullPointerException`s in the following code:

```
public class BasePage extends LoadableComponent<BasePage>{
    @Inject
    protected WebDriver driver  //trying to inject a WebDriver instance here

    public BasePage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);    
    }
    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {//something here}
    @Override
    protected void load() {//something as well}

    // some more shared methods   
}
```

Above is my `BasePage` class, `LoginPage` extends `BasePage` as below

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    @FindBy(id="login_username")
    private WebElement userNameField;
    @FindBy(id="login_password")
    private WebElement passWordField;
    @FindBy(id="login_database")
    private WebElement dataBase;

    public void enterValidLoginCredentials() throws FileNotFoundException {
        userNameField.sendKeys(EdgeTestProperties.getProperty("userName"));
        passWordField.sendKeys(EdgeTestProperties.getProperty("password"));
        dataBase.sendKeys(EdgeTestProperties.getProperty("db"));
    }        

    //some more tests here        

}
```

My step definitions login tests:

```
@ScenarioScoped
public class LoginSteps {

    private LoginPage login;

    @Inject
    LoginSteps(LoginPage login) {
    this.login = login;
    }

    @Given("^I'm on the login page$")
        public void getLoginPage() throws FileNotFoundException {
        login.get();    
    }

    @When("^I enter valid user credential")
    public void enterValidUserCredential() throws FileNotFoundException {
        login.enterValidLoginCredentials();
    }
```

In my `CucumberModule` I used:

```
public class CucumberModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        requestStaticInjection(BasePage.class);     
    }

    @Provides
    @ScenarioScoped
    WebDriver getWebDriver(){
        WebDriver driver = null;

        try {
            driver =  Browser.loadDriver(EdgeTestProperties.getProperty("browser"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.print("Failed to load the browser preference, check test properties file....");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

        return driver;
    }
}
```

When I start running the login test, the `@Inject`ion of the driver on `BasePage` only happens after the base constructor is called (initialization of the `WebElement`s). As a result, none of the `WebElement`s are initialized, so I get `NullPointerException`. I could get it to work if I remove the super class constructor and change the driver injection point to the `LoginPage` constructor and pass it back to the `BasePage` by a method which sets the driver and the initialise `WebElement`s, however that seems wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should use **Constructor** injection.

This will solve your problem, as the driver will now be available in the constructor.

```
protected final Webdriver driver;

@Inject
public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
}
```

You should be aware that, generally speaking, field injection is not preferred. You have discovered one reason; another reason is that it's [hard to test.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) Constructor injections are more verbose, but it also makes it much more clear what's going on, both when reading the code and when trying to write tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply durron597, see the thing is if i inject the driver through base constructor, i think it means I should implement constructors with same webdriver argument for all child classes which somewhat opposes my intention to have a centralised shared driver instance?

Comment: @TonyZhang why does it do that? There's no difference between the two injection types from the perspective of using a centralized driver instance. `@ScenarioScoped` should handle that for you just fine; you'll pass the argument into the super constructor in all your base classes i.e. `@Inject public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) { super(driver); }`

Comment: you are right actually, refactored the code now all works beatifully, thanks :)

Comment: @TonyZhang glad I could help! Don't forget to click the checkmark underneath the vote buttons!